# How do I stub and spy at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

So I'm testing a function that calls another function, that returns a promise, SUT looks like this:

```
fn($modal) -> 
    modalInstance = $modal.open({
       controller: 'myCtrl'
       size: 'lg'
     })

    modalInstance.result.then(updateData)
```

now If I need to test it I could start with something like this:

```
it 'when modal called, results get updated with right data', ->

   $modal = {
      open: sinon.stub().returns({ 
          result: $q.when([1, 2, 3]) 
      })
   }

   fn($modal)
```

and then check if the `updatedData` is equal to [1,2,3]

but I'd like to also make sure that `$modal.open` has been called and correct parameters been passed into it. How do I do that?

I need to not only stub the method but also spy on it, should I mock entire `$modal`? Can you  help me with the right syntax?

When I do something like this:

```
mMk  = sinon.mock($modal)
mMk.expects('open')
```

Sinon yells at me:
    `TypeError: Attempted to wrap open which is already stubbed`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stubs in Sinon support the full spy API, so you can do something like this:

```
// override $modal
$modal = {
    open: sinon.stub().returns({
        result: $q.when([1, 2, 3])
    });
};

fn($modal);
expect($modal.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
```

Note that if `$modal` is an injectable service, it may be cleaner to just stub the `open` method rather than override the entire `$modal`.

```
// override $modal.open
sinon.stub($modal, 'open').returns({
    result: $q.when([1, 2, 3])
});
```